# determine if drive is removable (flash or HDD) knowing only the drive letter

Tags: windows, model-view-controller, drive

I am trying to determine if a file is on a local drive. I found [GetDriveType() WINAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which retrieves the drive type. However reading the description of the return values it seems, and thats how I understand it, that it retrieves a flash drive as FIXED which is not what I want.

Its working fine on local drives:

```
bool IsDriveRemovableOrRemote(CString driveRoot)
{
    UINT driveType = GetDriveType(driveRoot);
    return (DRIVE_REMOVABLE == driveType || DRIVE_CDROM == driveType || DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR == driveType || DRIVE_REMOTE == driveType);
}
```

I don't have a flash/external drive to test ATM but I would like if someone can tell me if my interpretation is correct? and if so, what better alternative should I use?

Please bear in mind that I only have the path of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the doco more closely. While a Flash drive is considered a fixed device, there's a note in that linked page:

> To determine whether a drive is a USB-type drive, call SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty and specify the SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY property.

The process seems a little messy if all you start with is the path but you can start reading the doco [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff541247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It looks like you may need to enumerate the devices until you find one matching your drive.

To avoid doing this to all your requests, I would do a two-stage check. If your current method says it's not fixed, treat it as non-local.

If it says it *is* fixed, then you can enumerate the devices using my suggested method to be certain.

Alternatively, you can enumerate all fixed non-USB drives the first time you need to, and then just cache the information. I'm pretty certain that the list of these drives won't change while the system is running - drives that get added and deleted are, by definition, removable.

Comment: I did read that and researched it but all examples that uses it, they enumerate all available devices which is not usable in my case as I don't want to enumerate every time my utility receives a file to process

Comment: @Red, I would go for a two-stage approach which will hopefully avoid this, or just cache the information - see the update.

Comment: Thanks, will wait and see if there is any other solution. If not then this will probably be the method to use

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [DeviceIoControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and query for the `BusType = BusTypeUsb` by passing `IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY` as its second parameter. Read **Determining USB** by Thomas Lee at the bottom of [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: this is only to determine the bus type. If I would want to check for USB devices or firewire, I wont hesitate using that approach. However there are external SCSI drives out there for example and I cannot rule them out.

Comment: I don't think there is any 100% reliable method.  Consider things like eSATA; an internal drive connected to an internal port, but housed in an external enclosure.