# How do I check if a DeviceObject is a portable device (like usb flash drive or a cd)

Tags: c++, c, windows, kernel, driver

I'm writing a windows filter driver which needs to block all write operations on portable devices, I got the blocking part, but struggle to determine the device type. What I have is an Irp and a DeviceObject for every write operation attempted on the PC. I tried getting bit flags from DeviceObject like this `DeviceObject->Characteristics & FILE_REMOVABLE_MEDIA` for all the possible flags described on microsoft, but it is always set at FILE_REMOTE_DEVICE and FILE_DEVICE_ALLOW_APPCONTAINER_TRAVERSAL, whether the usb flash drive is installed or not.
What is the correct way to check for it?

Comment: Is this a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45045670/reliably-know-if-a-volume-is-removable-or-not-with-winapi

Comment: I don't think I can use it in a driver.